# How to write this Linq-to-SQL select query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, select

I have 3 tables: subcontracts, companies and contacts.  Each table has a active_status flags which shows that the item is still active (hasn't been deleted).

- Each contact has a company_id field which stores the id of the contact's company.
- Each subcontract has a company_id field which stores the subcontract's company.
- Each company has a company_id field which holds its guid and a primary_company field, b/c the company could be a subsidiary.  If it's a subsidiary, the primary_company field holds the id of the primary company.

I have a subcontract form.  On the form, I have a drop-down of contacts which are stored in a contact table.  Currently the drop-down lists all contacts.  I would like to have the drop-down only list contacts which belong to the subcontract's company or any of that company's subsidiaries.

I have the following query which I use elsewhere in the program to pass a company_id and get its subsidiaries.

```
public IQueryable<company> GetSubsidiaryCompanies(Guid id)
{
   return
      from c in db.companies
      where c.primary_company == id && c.active_status == true
      select c;
}
```

This is my current contact selection

```
public IQueryable<contact> GetContacts()
{
   return
      from c in db.contacts
      where c.active_status == true
      orderby c.contact_name
      select c;
}
```

What I need to do is pass it the subcontract.company_id and then only return the contacts where `contact.company_id == subcontract.company_id` or `contact.company_id ==` one of the subsidiary ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<contact> GetContacts(Guid id)
{
    return 
    db.companies
        .Where(c=>c.active_status == true) 
        .Where(c=>c.primary_company == id || c.company_id == id)
        .SelectMany(c=>c.contacts);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IQueryable<contact> GetActiveCompanies(Guid id)
{
    return from c in db.companies 
           where c.active_status == true
              && (c.primary_company == id || c.company_id == id)
           select c;
}

public IQueryable<contact> GetContacts(Guid id)
{
    return GetActiveCompanies(id)
          .SelectMany(c=>c.contacts);
}
```